# Ubuntu background task sockets running on Mono

Tags: c#, sockets, mono, network-programming

Basically I have this server app I built in vc#, and for some reason when I run the task like this

```
mono oserver.exe &
```

It continues to run, but I can't connect to it.
But if I just call it normally like this

```
mono oserver.exe
```

it works fine?
Is there a better way to do this that works? Or maybe certain things that mono can't do in the background? Not sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what I ended up finding out was that the working directory of the app changed as I moved the app from forground to background with fg and bg. I have no idea why this would happen, but making absolute paths in my app allowed my app to run in the backgound. I also used mono oserver & > /dev/null.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
mono oserver.exe & some-another-command
```

?

Comment: Actually what I ended up finding out was that the working directory of the app changed as I moved the app from forground to background with fg and bg. I have no idea why this would happen, but making absolute paths in my app allowed my app to run in the backgound. I also used mono oserver & > /dev/null.